# gnuplot: including simulation parameters in a box at the top right corner

Tags: gnuplot

I am new to gnuplot. Can anyone please tell me as to how do I include my simulation parameters in a box at the top right corner of the plot? I want the parameter box to be visible just below the legends which are used for displaying the actual curves.

I want to include only three parameters of the form:

```
"GraphConnectivity: 0.2"
"Query: 0.2"
"Content: 0.2"
```

which should be visible in a box just below the legends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.2/rectangle.html) has a pretty nice way of placing a label in a box (in gnuplot 4.2+).

To see how this would work with multiple lines in your label, try copying and replacing the lines below into the example from the link:

```
#
# Illustrate using character widths to put a box around a label
#

# each line of the label gets a separate variable here
label1 = "Label in"
label2 = "a box"
label3 = "rocks"
LABEL = label1."\n".label2."\n".label3
# this bit finds the longest part of the multi-line string
# to determine the box width
longlabel = (strlen(label1) > strlen(label2)) ? label1 : label2
longlabel = (strlen(longlabel) > strlen(label3)) ? longlabel : label3

# change 'char 2' below to reflect the number of lines in the label.
# you will also have to adjust the y-position of the rectangle manually
set obj 10 rect at -3,(-4-0.4) size char strlen(longlabel), char 3
set obj 10 fillstyle empty border -1 front
set label 10 at -3,-4 LABEL front center
```

Answer (score 2):

To add labels, you want `set label`...

e.g.

```
XVAL=???
YVAL=???
set label "GraphConnectivity: 0.2\nQuery: 0.2\nContent: 0.2" at screen XVAL,screen YVAL
```

You'll need to play around with XVAL and YVAL a little to get the label to show up where you want it.

Alternatively, you could use 3 set label commands:

```
set label "GraphConnectivity: 0.2" at screen XVAL, screen YVAL
set label "Query: 0.2" at screen XVAL, screen YVAL offset character 0,-1
set label "Content: 0.2" at screen XVAL, screen YVAL offset character 0,-2
```

To put a box around the labels, you could use arrows without heads, or you could use the `set object rectangle` command